# Equals Not Working VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to compare two strings that I know are equal to each other, but it is always skipping to the else. I've tried everything, .Equals, =, IsNot, they all don't work! The frustrating part is that I know the strings are equal! Please take a look at my code and see if it there is possible anything wrong with it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim log As String
    WithEvents xworker As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    xworker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub xWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles xworker.DoWork
    Dim qWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    Dim client As New Net.WebClient
    log = client.DownloadString("http://########/log.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub xWorker_Completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles xworker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If log.Equals(RichTextBox1.Text) Then
        xworker.RunWorkerAsync()
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Text = log
        xworker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: They probably aren't actually equal.

Comment: just put a breakpoint on the line where the comparison is happening and see what the values are when the code reaches that point. They are probably not what you expect

Comment: The thing is, they are. I just set a breakpoint and saw both variables. Sure enough they were both exactly the same.
RichTextBox1.Text "log test 1234" String
|  log "log test 1234" String

Comment: Check `.Length` on each one.

Comment: They are not, a machine does not lie.  With the most obvious possible reason that there are difference that you cannot see.  Like the line endings, "\n" in RichTextBox and "\r\n" in the file.

Comment: Is there any solution to this, because as you can see, I am directly setting RichTextBox1.Text to log, so there should not be any difference.

Comment: Visually equal and binary equal are two different thing. Try copy&paste this: `Dim isEqual = ("А" = "A")`

Comment: Then there's no point in checking if they are the same.  Which is certainly the approach you should pursue, comparing the text line-by-line is pretty expensive.

Comment: Sorry, Despite all your effort, none of these solutions are working for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to listen to @SLaks and @Hans Passant, they were right on the money.

I setup your code sample and it worked correctly if the source log.txt file didn't have a line terminator in it.  Once I added the line terminator I got the results your are getting.

From the command window:

```
>? RichTextBox1.Text.Length
14
>? log.length
15
```

Using the QuickWatch window, and TABing until the Value field was selected:

Log result:

```
"log test 1234" & vbCrLf & ""
```

RichTextBox result:

```
"log test 1234" & vbLf & ""
```

The fix to the problem depends on what will actually get written to the log.txt file.  I assume that "log test 1234" is just development code.  If you are only interested in a single line as a result code then make sure you are not writing a line terminator.  If your result codes are more complicated then you will need to do more parsing on the result than just an Equals compare.

Comment: I am attempting to remotely log a server, which will be constantly writing new lines every couple seconds or so. the program on the remote machine is sending the log file to a web server via FTP, then the program reads it and displays it to me in the rich textbox. The whole reason why I am using this check is because the rich textbox is flashing, probably because it is being updated too quickly. I don't want to change the update time because I want to be able to see it close to real time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

If log.ToLower().Trim() = RichTextBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim() Then

Answer (score 0):

I think this is case sensitve compare. You should convert both of the strings to upper or to lower and then compare them

```
If Log.ToLower() = RichTextBox1.Text.ToLower() Then
```

Or you can use String.Compare method and set third param to true to ignore case

```
If String.Compare(log, RichTextBox1.Text, True) = 0 Then
```

Comment: I can now see that the problem is being caused by the string being updated every second. As soon as I loaded up the program that is sending the programs log to the web server, it started saying that they were not equal, even though nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that the RichTextBox can change line endings when Text gets set. So the Text property might be returning a string that is different than what was set. I haven't been able to verify, but you can probably devise a quick test of this theory.